# PHP - How to use Foreach to turn a list into a column rather than a row of items?

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

I have a database, and am trying to get a list using PHP with foreach, but  the list are returning like this:

`RiquelmeMacielLewBrMarcuus`

But it like so:

`RiquelmeMaciel
 LewBr
 Marcuus`

My code:

```
<?php 
        include_once("conexao.php");    
        $select = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY id";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
              ?>
              <?php foreach($rows as $row){
              echo '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric name">'.$row['nome'].'</td>';
              } ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert table rows to create the rows:

```
<?php 
//Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados
include_once("conexao.php");

$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY id";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

foreach($resultado_usuario as $teste){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric name">'.$teste['nome'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"></td>';
    echo '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Now you just need to add in your variables for 'EMAIL' and 'SENHA'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your foreach cycle - for eache element you output  tag, but  is a table cell tag.

If you want fill first column in your 3-column table, you must do something like this:

```
<?php foreach($resultado_usuario as $teste){
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric name">'.$teste['nome'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>second column</td>';
     echo '<td>third column</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are displaying your data the wrong way, your `<td>` should be inside `<tr>` which should be inside a `<table>`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Senha</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($resultado_usuario as $teste){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric name">'.$teste['nome'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric email">'.$teste['email'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric senha">'.$teste['senha'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

The data will then be displayed as you wanted it. Have a look at [HTML - table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

If you want to change the order of your data from your **SQL query**, use the [ORDER BY ... ASC|DESC](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp).